# Reading multiple integers on a line to a listbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to read all of the integers in a list box line.

```
Dim scores As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(line, "\d+")
```

I have saved the scores in a format like this

> Name 00 00 00

Could I have the regular expression for reading 3 integers with a space in between each number? The file the integers are stored in is a notepad file.

Comment: @Alexander yes it is a text file. But i have to used it for my assignment.

Comment: This regular expression does what you need I'm pretty sure, Regex.IsMatch(Line, "^\d{2}\s{1}\d{2}\s{1}\d{2}$") You can now give it functionality to what you want.

Comment: @Timmy this expression only reads the first integer of the line I want it to read all of them

Comment: @user4838397 I just quickly tested the expression I gave you and if the expression is a match `scores.ToString` returned what I had entered in. Maybe I'm not 100% clear on what you are asking for.  Also the `Regex.IsMatch` Will test for if the line given matches the regular expression, so it is a Boolean and will return either `True` or `False`. I'm not sure if that helps at all, if not I'm not clear on what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Approach without regex:

```vb
Const SEPARATOR As String = " "c
Dim line As String 'Here reading line from the file
Dim numbers As New List(Of Int32)()
Dim values As String() = line.Split(SEPARATOR) 'Split values to array
For Each value As String in values
    Dim tempnumber As Int32
    If Int32.TryParse(value, tempnumber) = True Then
        'Accept only numbers
        numbers.Add(tempnumber)
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Matches` instead of `Match` and store the results of the `Regex` into a `MatchCollection`

```
Sub Main()
    Dim scores As String = "00 13 00"
    Dim score As System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(scores, "\d+")

    For i As Integer = 0 To score.Count - 1
        Console.WriteLine(score.Item(i))
    Next

    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Results:

[image]